# Calculating partial derivative.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f=f(x,y)$ a function of two times continuously differentiable.

**Given :**

$\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x^2}}-\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{y^2}}=0$

$f(x,2x)=x$

$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}(x,2x)=x^2$

**Question:**

Find $\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x^2}}(x,2x)$ and $\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x}\partial{y}}(x,2x)$.

I've tried determining the function $f(x,y)$ out of the given info but in vain and I'm not even sure if it's possible to determine the function $f(x,y)$ as there could be multiple functions with the same partial derivatives? (correct me if I'm wrong).

So I'm assuming there's a simple way to solve this problem.

If anyone could give me hints or point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it!

I'd also be grateful if anyone knows somewhere where i could find similar problems to this one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure that $f(x,2x)=x$? it is not consistent with $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}(x,2x)=x^2$

Comment: @gimusi: I don't think that should be a problem. Define $f(x,y):=x^3/3-y^3/24+y/2$. Then, $f(x,2x)=x^3/3-x^3/3+x=x$ but $f_x(x,2x)=x^2$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas $f_x(x,2x)=x^2+2(-(2x)^2/8+1/2)=1$

Comment: @gimusi: Shouldn't taking partial derivative wrt $x$ make $f_x(x,y)=x^2-0+0=x^2$ ?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Let apply chain rule to $$f(x,y(x))\implies f'(x)=f_x+f_y(y=2x)\cdot y'(x)$$

Comment: @gimusi: I don't think chain rule is intended here. It's more likely that the problem states $f,f_x$ evaluated at points $(x,y)=(k,2k)$ is $k$ and $k^2$ respectively.

Comment: @Holo Let define $g(x)=f(x,y(x))$ with $y(x)=2x$ and apply chain rule.

Comment: $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x ,y) = x^2,$$ so substituting $2x$ for $y$ we get $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x ,2x) = x^2.$$

Comment: Given $f(x,y):=x^3/3-y^3/24+y/2$ we have $$f_x(x,2x)=x^2-y(x)^2/8*y'(x)+(1/2)*y'(x)=x^2-x^2+1=1$$

Comment: @gimusi: I understand your comment but I think that's not the intent of OP's problem. When you calculate $f_x(x,2x)$, you're basically calculating $\Phi'(x)$ where $\Phi(x):=f(x,2x)$; this $\Phi$ is a function different from $f$. But I think the OP's problem instead says that if $\Phi(x,y):=f_x(x,y)$, then $\Phi(x,2x)=x^2$; the two notions are different.

Comment: I think the problem just states that given a function $f(x,y)$ if we substitute $y$ with $2x$ we get $f(x,2x) =x$ and then if we get the partial derivative with respect to x while keeping y as a constant , and then substitute y with 2x into the expression of $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}$ we get $x^2$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Ah ok now it is clear! Thanks

Comment: @PrasunBiswas I agree with you: that was the intent of the OP's problem. But it's no use talking about somebody's intentions. The most important thing is that is the standard meaning of the symbol $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, 2x).$$

Comment: @Raku Yes sorry I didn't get that point at first.

Comment: @Raku: Your post is still unclear. At the end of the first line of your post, is it given to you that $f$ is harmonic or do you have to verify it? You should also explain your notation carefully so that others do not misinterpret it.

Comment: Assuming that by harmonic you mean twice continuously differentiable function ,It's included in the first line.If you're referring to something else let me kwow and i'll edit It.

Comment: @Raku: By harmonic, I mean $f_{xx}+f_{yy}=0$. Functions which satisfy the Laplacian operator, i.e., $\nabla\cdot\nabla f=0$ are called harmonic.

Comment: It's given , I'll edit it to make it clear , thanks.

Comment: It seems like i've made a typo in the question it should be $f_{xx}-f_{yy}=0$ sorry for the trouble!

Comment: It's a Cauchy problem for the wave equation and can be treated accordingly. Writing out the general solution in the form  $f(x,y)=g_1(x-y)+g_2(x+y)$ and inserting in the initial conditions one gets a unique solution written down in the second comment in the answer of @p4sch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(x) := f(x,2x)$. Then we know that $g(x) =x$. Thus by multidimensional chain-rule
$$\tag{1} 1= g'(x) = \partial_x f(x,2x)+2\partial_y f(x,2x).$$
This shows that
$$\partial_y f(x,2x) = \frac{1-x^2}{2}.$$
Now, we apply the same argument to $h(x) = \partial_x f(x,2x) =x^2$. This gives
$$\tag{2}2x = h'(x)= \partial_x^2 f(x,2x) + 2 \partial_{xy} f(x,2x).$$
And for $l(x):=\partial_y f(x,2x)$, we have
$$\tag{3}-x = l'(x) = \partial_{xy} f(x,2x)+2 \partial_{y}^2 f(x,2x).$$
Subtracting $2 \times(2)-(3)$ gives
$$5x=3\partial_{xy} f(x,2x)+2\partial_x^2 f(x,2x)-2\partial_{y}^2 f(x,2x)=3\partial_{xy} f(x,2x),$$
because $\partial_x^2 f = \partial_y^2 f$. So we find
$$\partial_{xy} f(x,2x) =\frac{5}{3}x.$$
Inserting in $(3)$ gives now
$$\partial_{x}^2 f(x,2x)=\partial_{y}^2 f(x,2x) = - \frac{4}{3} x.$$
**Additonal Comment**: However, the question is if such a function exists and if it is unique.

**Second Comment:** By solving a linear equation I have cooked up following example:
$$f(x,y)=- \frac{13}{18} x^2 y+\frac{7}{9}y^2 x+\frac{7}{27}x^3-\frac{13}{54} y^3+\frac{1}{2}y$$
As Andrew commented, the equation in question is a Cauchy problem for the wave equation and can be treated accordingly. Thus, the solution is unique.

Comment: What i don't understand is how $\partial_x f(x,2x)=x^{2}$. Is this supposed to be the same as the one given in the question? I thought the one given in the question is determined by calculating the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to x , then substituting $y$ with $2x$ whereas the one in the differential is determined by taking the partial derivative with respect to x of our new function $f(x,2x)$ which should be equal to 1?

Comment: It is just an abuse of notation: We may write $\partial_1 f(x,y)$ for the derivate in the first direction and $\partial_2f(x,y)$ for the derviate in the second direction. Then we have for example for $g(x)=f(x,2x)$, writing $T(x) = (x,2x)$, that $h'(x) = (D_{(x,2x)}f) \circ D_{x} T  = \partial_1 f(x,2x) + 2\partial_2 f(x,2x)$. So here $\partial_1 f(x,2x)$ is the partial derivate of $f$ with respect of $x$ in the point $(x,2x)$. On the other hand, we know that $g'(x) =1$ ...

Comment: It should be $\partial_x^2$ in the last equation, shouldn't it? Nice answer and thank you for providing me the means to check my own :)

Comment: We know that $\partial_{x}^2 f(x,2x)=\partial_{y}^2 f(x,2x)$, so it is the same.

Comment: @p4sch, re: your last update. It's not just an example, it's the unique solution I believe, since I have obtained the same function. Very nice

Comment: Yes, it is! As Andrew pointed out in the comments it is a Cauchy-Problem and the solution is unique.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on various comments:

*Claim.* A function $f:\>{\mathbb R}^2\to{\mathbb R}$ satisfying the wave equation $f_{xx}-f_{yy}\equiv0$ can be written in the form
$$f(x,y)=a(x-y)+b(x+y)\tag{1}$$
for certain functions $a$, $b$ of one variable.

This is very well known. Here is a *sketch of proof*: Consider the auxiliary function
$$g(u,v):=f\left({u+v\over2},{-u+v\over2}\right)\ .$$
Using $f_{xx}-f_{yy}\equiv0$ one easily verifies that $g_{uv}\equiv0$, i.e.,  $(g_u)_v\equiv0$. This implies that $g_u$ depends only on $u$, and one further integration gives $g(u,v)=a(u)+b(v)$, hence
$$f(x,y)=g(x-y,x+y)=a(x-y)+b(x+y)\ .\qquad\square$$
We are given that
$$f(x,2x)=a(-x)+b(3x)=x\ ,$$
which implies $f(0,0)=0$ and
$$-a'(-x)+3b'(3x)=1\ .\tag{2}$$
Furthermore $f_x(x,y)=a'(x-y)+b'(x+y)$
implies $f_x(x,2x)=a'(-x)+b'(3x)$, so that we obtain the condition
$$a'(-x)+b'(3x)=x^2\ .\tag{3}$$
Solving $(2)\wedge(3)$ gives
$$a'(-x)={3x^2-1\over 4},\qquad b'(3x)={x^2+1\over4}$$
and therefore
$$a'(x)={3x^2-1\over4},\qquad b'(x)={x^2+9\over36}\ .$$
Since we may take $a(0)=b(0)=0$ we then obtain
$$a(x)={x^3-x\over4},\qquad b(x)={x^3+27x\over108}\ .$$
Plugging this into $(1)$ gives the uniquely determined $f$ appearing as "example" in p4sch's answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very direct way of solving this. Because we are always interested in $y$ around $2x$, let's just represent the function as a series:

$$f(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(x) (y-2x)^k$$

Immediately we can see from the last two conditions:

$$a_0(x)=x$$

$$a_0'(x)-2a_1(x)=x^2 \quad \Rightarrow a_1(x)=\frac{1-x^2}{2}$$

And from the first condition after some work:

$$a_k''-4(k+1)a_{k+1}'+3(k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2}=0$$

And now we can find every coefficient:

$$a_k=\frac{4(k-1) a_{k-1}'-a_{k-2}''}{3k(k-1)}$$

We find:

> $$a_2=\frac{-4x}{6}=-\frac{2}{3} x$$

Now to get the answers we need:

> $$f_{xx} (x,2x)=a_0''-4a_1'+8a_2=4x-\frac{16}{3} x=-\frac{4}{3} x$$
>
> $$f_{xy} (x,2x)=a_1'-4a_2=-x+\frac{8}{3} x=\frac{5}{3} x$$

---

Using the recursion formula further, we obtain:

$$a_3=-\frac{13}{54}$$

$$a_{k >3}=0$$

Which makes the function to be:

$$f(x,y)=x+\frac{1}{2}(1-x^2)(y-2x)-\frac{2}{3} x (y-2x)^2-\frac{13}{54}  (y-2x)^3=$$

$$=\frac{1}{54} (14 x^3 - 39 x^2 y + 42 x y^2 - 13 y^3 + 27 y)$$